# Delay background color opacity until background image loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a background image visible through an opaque color screen in my website's header. The background image is set in a CSS file and is optimized so it cannot be made any smaller in size. When the cache is clear, you can see the image slowly loading even when fully optimized on a pretty fast internet connection (~150 mbps).

So my question is: is there a way to delay the opacity - i.e. use a solid version of the background screen - until the background image is fully loaded, and then switch to the opaque version? I'm thinking there may be a JS/jQuery solution but I'm still at a basic level with those, and my search turned up very little. I tried a CSS animation delay, but that's not really ideal since it depends on real timing, not when the image is known to be loaded.

I'm open to other suggestions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsanzer/63dyv9jo/) demonstrating the HTML and CSS, and there's an embedded example below as well.

```css
.bg-wrapper {width: 500px; height: 250px; background: url(https://unsplash.it/2000/1000); background-position: 50% 0%; background-size: cover;}
.bg {width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #FF4136; background: rgba(255,65,54,0.9)}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper">
 <div class="bg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could like this, using a pseudo element and an image load event, where it reads the image path from your CSS rule ... updated, to target an array of elements

```js
(function(el){
  el.forEach(function(e) {
    var style = e.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(e, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/["|']/g, "");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { e.classList.add('loaded'); }
    img.src = bi;  
  });
})(document.querySelectorAll('.bg-wrapper'));
```

```css
.bg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/);
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: cover;
}
.bg-wrapper.nr2 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/2/);
}
.bg-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.bg-wrapper.loaded::before {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.bg-wrapper * {
  position: relative;    /*  this make content stay ontop  */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper">
 <div>
   This is content.....
 </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-wrapper nr2">
 <div>
   This is content.....
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you mean something like opacity: 0.9 for the after portion?

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone Yes, updated, and mainly wanted to show how to read image src from CSS rule and using a pseudo

Comment: Do you see a particular advantage to this over @MichaelCoker 's suggestion?

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone Yes, less markup, closed function which does not pollute the global scope, not to have to set image source twice

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone Updated showing how to target an array of elements ... note though, the main trick here was what _Michael_ suggested, the load handler

Comment: In my real life situation there is content inside the wrapper div, so the pseudo element solution isn't working so well because it covers that content. I do, however, like the idea of pulling the image from the CSS.

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone I will update to show how to solve when having content inside

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yep, move the opaque background to a separate class, then using JS, create a new `Image()`, assign the image URL as the `src` and use an `onload` event on that image to add the opaque class to your `.bg` element.

If you want to fade the opacity change, then use `opacity` on `.bg` instead of `rgba()` and transition the `opacity` property.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0].classList.add('opaque');
}
img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/1000/500?image=763';
```

```css
.bg-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/500?image=763);
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FF4136;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.opaque {
  opacity: .9
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper">
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the main problem; you're awesome. Does this method allow a quick way to fade between the solid and opaque states?